# java, connect to filesystem of another computer/server with a gui

Tags: java, user-interface, connection

Solution?

-- it looks like i may be able to use the x-11 forwarding in jsch and and use the java Desktop class to launch a file browser. Not sure if this will work.

What I am trying to do is, within a java application, open a connection to a server or another computer. I have found a way to do this that opens a terminal window but what I want is a gui/explorer/finder like window that allows me to drag and drop files between the machines.

--Edit--
An example: When i use an sftp application i can open a graphical window and drag files from my computer to folders on the remote server. just like an explorer or finder window. I am looking for a way to implement this type of functionality in java. I want to open a connection to a remote machine, then open a graphical window to browse the file system

Comment: What did you look into? Creating a GUI is different to coding the actual file manipulation in the backend.

Comment: @Femaref i dont necessarily want to program the gui myself. i was thinking something like when i use the go/connect to server application in osx. i want to be able to open a window to sftp (or something similarly secure) files between machines

Comment: @Femaref feel free to point me in the right direction if you think there is a better way to phrase the question i am trying to ask

Comment: You could use [sshfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to create a mount point for the remote file system on your machine, and use your normal tools. I had this working on Mac OS X and debian, works like a charm. Windows is a different beast though.

Comment: @Femaref if i must i can implement multiple connection methods depending on the environments used but i would really love to find a more simple way

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to communicate with the server through SSH and 
1. create your own GUI or
2. use X11 forwarding

Comment: @almalki ive read a little about jSch and X11 forwarding, I have not had luck figuring out how to open a local window into the filesystem after the connection has been made

Comment: well, don't you drop platform indepency with the 2nd approach?

Comment: @MadProgrammer same question to you as i just asked almalki

Comment: @Zhedar it was my understanding that x11 works on windows and mac? was incorrect?

Comment: @Andrew Actually it wasn't shipped on my OSX 10.8.2 by default, but it should be available for those systems. If you use your application just for yourself, those dependencies would NOT be a problem, otherwise I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: @Andrew I wouldn't bother trying to open a x11 window.  Just use `JSch` to open a `SSH` terminal session to the remote system and execute commands directly to it (like `pwd`, `ls` etc)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer basically, opening a window that i can use to drag and drop files between machines is the whole point of the app. I don't necessarily need it to be X11 if there is another easier way, but sometimes i dont feel like using terminal commands

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I should have clarified.  Basicaly you just want to use JSch to provide you with a "virtual" file system.  Much like you would list local files in a `JList` or `JTree`, you would use `JSch` to provide you with the data from the remote system to do the same.  `JSch` has a number of examples for copying files as well. I did this when we need to build a staging and release system for our application to client sites. It would browse the remote system, finding the files it need to verify, copied our application files up and installed them (if required)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i still am not sure i have made it clear what i am trying to do. For example. When i use an sftp application i can open a graphical window and drag files from my computer to folders on the remote server. just like an explorer or finder window. I am looking for a way to implement this type of functionality in java. I want to open a connection to a remote machine, then open a graphical window to browse the file system

Comment: @Zhedar well, it will not if you use native java impl of x server

Comment: @Andrew you can create your own GUI filesystem browser on top of JSch or use something similar to http://j-ftp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @almalki interesting. I was hoping there was a library already available. It looks like i may be in for a little work here.

Comment: @andrew yep, exactly. JSch will allow you to interrogate the remote file system so you can generate a view on the client

Answer (score 0):

you need two applications in each machine ,you can do this by TLS connection.
however it need a waiting thread in costumer machine (dragable) to get file from Tls port and stream it to new location or if  you want to use just gui in one machine you can old applet or java Fx instead .

Comment: You don't really need two applications, at least if you want to connect to a unix server - just use `ssh`, `scp` or `sftp` to connect to them; if you wan't multiple windows, run separate connections.